# Learning archiving

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Im trying to save and load the settings of a simple application. However im still new to obj-c. I do believe the saving part is working, but not the loading part. When i change the settings, press back and reenter the settingsview, the settings are not loaded.

I think it's something with how the SettingsViewController is created with the saved data, but i cannot wrap my head around it.

Below is the interesting code from the SettingsViewController, and further below, from the MainWindowViewController

SettingsViewController:

```
-(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if(self)
    {
        NSString * path = [self settingsArchivePath];

        self = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:path];
        shakeSwitch.on = shakeForTag;
        [warningDistanceFld setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",warningDistance]];

}
return self;
}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    self = [super initWithNibName:@"SettingsViewController" bundle:nil];
    if(self)
    {
        [self setShakeForTag:[aDecoder decodeBoolForKey:@"shakeForTag"]];
        [self setWarningDistance:[aDecoder decodeIntForKey:@"warningDistance"]];
        [self setMapType:[aDecoder decodeIntegerForKey:@"mapType"]];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
    [aCoder encodeInt:warningDistance forKey:@"warningDistance"];
    [aCoder encodeBool:shakeForTag forKey:@"shakeForTag"];
    [aCoder encodeInteger:mapType forKey:@"mapType"];
}

-(NSString *)settingsArchivePath
{
    NSArray *documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,    NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString * documentDirectory = [documentDirectories objectAtIndex:0];
    return [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"settings.archive"];
}

-(IBAction)back:(id)sender
{

    if([mapChanger selectedSegmentIndex] == 0){
        mapType = MKMapTypeSatellite;
    }else if([mapChanger selectedSegmentIndex] ==1){
        mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;
    }else{
        mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
    }

    NSString *warning = [warningDistanceFld text];
    warningDistance = [warning intValue];
    shakeForTag =shakeSwitch.on;

    [self saveChanges];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(BOOL)saveChanges
{
    NSString *path = [self settingsArchivePath];
    NSLog(@"saved");
   return [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:self toFile:path];
}
```

Code in MainWindowViewController to initialize the settingsViewController:

```
svc = [[SettingsViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SettingsViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

svc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentViewController:svc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: No need for this. You should simply use `NSUserDefaults` to save your app's settings.

Comment: certainly seems easier thanks! leave an answer to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an `NSKeyedArchiver` to save simple application's setting is a bit overkill.

The Foundation framework provides the **[`NSUserDefaults`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)** class, which is much easier to use.
This is the way to go, for iOS or OS X.

It will write a `plist` file in the correct location with your settings.

Writing something is basically:

```
[ [ NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults ] setBool: YES forKey: @"SettingsKey" ];
[ [ NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults ] setInteger: 42 forKey: @"SettingsKey" ];
[ [ NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults ] synchronise ];
```

The last line ensure data is written to disk. It's not mandatory, as it's invoked automatically at regular intervals, but it's usually safer to call it explicitly.

Getting data is basically:

```
[ [ NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults ] boolForKey: @"SettingsKey" ];
[ [ NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults ] integerForKey: @"SettingsKey" ];
```

`NSUserDefault` can manage a lot of data-types. Integers, boolean, floating-point, but also arrays (`NSArray`), dictionaries (`NSDictionary`), data (`NSData`), etc.

Also note that you can loads default settings from an existing `plist` file (i.e. in your app resources) with:

```
[ [ NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults ] registerDefaults: [ NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: @"path/to/plist" ] ];
```

Comment: Very helpful, and so much easier than what is was doing :) thanks